# Matrix of orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

It was required to find the orthogonal projection of the vector $u =(0,1,0,2)$ onto

$W=${$(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x+y-t = 0$} and the matrix of the projection.

First, I've found a basis for $W$ and, use Gram-Schimidt process, an orthonormal basis. With it, I could do the first part of the problem.

Having an orthonormal basis for my space, can this make the job of finding the matrix of the projection easier? If it does, how can I found this matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Having an orthonormal basis for my space, can this make the job of
>   finding the matrix of the projection easier? If it does, how can I
>   found this matrix?

Yes! If $\{\mathbf{q}_i\}$ forms an orthonormal basis for the subspace $W$ that you want to orthogonally project onto, then the matrix of the orthogonal projection is is just $QQ^T$, where the columns of $Q$ are the $\mathbf{q}_i$.

More generally, if $\{\mathbf{p}_i\}$ only forms an orthogonal (but not necessarily *orthonormal*) basis for $W$, then the matrix of the orthogonal projection on to $W$ is $P(P^T P)^{-1}P^T$, where $\mathbf{p}_i$ form the columns of $P$.

Comment: Thanks! thats what I was looking for.

Comment: The second formula works for _any_ basis, not only for an orthogonal one.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need a basis for $W$. A normal vector for $W$
is $\overrightarrow{n}=(1,1,0,-1)$, so for a vector
$\overrightarrow{v}=(x,y,z,t)$ the projection $p(\overrightarrow{v})$ of $\overrightarrow{v}$ is simply 
$\overrightarrow{v}-\frac{(\overrightarrow{v}.\overrightarrow{n})\overrightarrow{n}}{||\overrightarrow{n}||^2}$.

Here we have

$$
\lambda=\frac{(\overrightarrow{v}.\overrightarrow{n})}
{||\overrightarrow{n}||^2}=
\frac{x+y-t}{3},
$$

so the coordinates of the projection are

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x-\lambda &=& \frac{2x-y+t}{3} \\
y-\lambda &=& \frac{-x+2y+t}{3} \\
z &=& z \\
t+\lambda &=& \frac{x+y+2t}{3}
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

So the matrix of the projection is

$$
\frac{1}{3}\left(
\begin{matrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

In particular, the coordinates of the projection of
$\overrightarrow{u}$ is $\frac{1}{3}(1,4,0,5)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know this way of doing a projection. I need a basis for W since I use that $P_w = (u|u_1)u_1 + ... + (u|u_n)u_n$, where {$u_i$} is a basis of $W$

Comment: I think I can obtain my matrix using the form I told applying the projection to the vectors of one basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: You don't need a basis for $W$ because once you know the normal vector, you can find the part of any arbitrary vector that is normal to $W$ and subtract it off to get the orthogonal projection.  For any $v$, the orthogonal projection $P(v)$ is $v - (\hat n)(\hat n \cdot v)$.

Comment: Ok, but as I said, using the way I know (as you can see, I do not know much of this part, since I couldn't find a good book to study it yet), I do. I like the way it was make by Ewan, but I didnt know it until now.

Comment: @Muphrid yeah I get it. I mean I understand I do not need a basis, but this matrix is a matrix of a linear transformation in some bases anyway and my question is how do i know w.r.t which bases is the matrix in the solution. I mean imagine that I am asked to write out the basis of W that I am working on.